# sails test controller not executing completely

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I am using sailsjs v0.11

As mentioned in [testing](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing) documentation, I have configured my app.

My UserController.test.js

```
var request = require('supertest');
console.log('log 1');
describe('UserController', function() {
  console.log('log 2');
  describe('index', function() {
    console.log('log 3');
    it('should return success', function(done) {
      console.log('log 4');
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .get('/user')
        .expect(200, done);
    });
  });

});
```

My User.test.js

```
describe.only('UsersModel', function() {

  describe('#find()', function() {
    it('should check find function', function (done) {
      User.find()
        .then(function(results) {
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
  });

});
```

If i execute `PORT=9999 mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js` I can see only

```
log1
log2
log3
```

in my console. The code after `console.log(log3)` is not being executed. 
However My User.test.js in models is working fine.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: In your other test files, do you have a `describe.only` or an `it.only` anywhere? That would preclude the tests from running. Additionally, you should have a reporter configured. What is the reporter saying?

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Thanks. I have change `describe.only` as `describe` in my `User.test.js`. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed my `User.test.js` as @jedd.ahyoung mentioned in the comment and everything works fine

```
describe('UsersModel', function() {

  describe('#find()', function() {
    it('should check find function', function (done) {
      User.find()
        .then(function(results) {
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
  });

});
```